# What are Twitter's tricks for smooth UITableView scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having trouble improving the scrolling of my UITableView that has its custom cells laid out using autolayout. I have two types of custom UITableViewCell of different heights (one around 200px one around 500px) I have tried a LOT of things including:

1. Caching heights of UITableViewCells
2. Using automatic dimensions and estimated row height
3. Calculating heights of UITableViewCells (this may need some looking into, anyone have links for a proper way to do this with a custom tableviewcell?)
4. using opaque views
5. Trying to use instruments to see where the slow downs are occurring
6. Moving code from `cellForRowAt` to `willDisplayCell`
7. Caching and displaying attributed text asynchronously.
8. Caching and displaying images asynchronously.

As well as following numerous online guides that claim to improve scrolling speed. However, the scrolling is still jerky!

Also, when I try to scroll to the top cell, it sometimes doesn't reach the top. I guess the estimated cell height has something to do with that, but it's hard to get it right because of the varying heights of cells.

Instruments suggests that my code slows down when I set the text into the label of my cell (thats the bit that adjusts the cell height).

I'm trying to work out how the Twitter app (which has basically the same functionality as my UITableView, with attributed text, and images etc), has such good scrolling. I saw a blog post a while back from them saying how the use drawRect for everything, however, I'm pretty sure they don't do that now. Anyone have any insights in to how they achieve 60fps smooth scrolling?

### My Code

So the first thing is my two table cells have the following structure:

**Table Cell 1:**

```
 - UITableViewCell
     - UIView (content view)
         - UIView (Shadow view)
             - UIView (Card background)
                 - UIView x 3
                 - UIButton x 5
                 - UILabel x 2
                 - UITextView
```

The reason I have the UIViews called `shadow view` and `card background` is because I add a `shadowPath` to `shadow view`s layer which is a `UIBezierPath`. Then I add a radius to `card background`. These two could not be done on the same layer because the radius is only in two of the corners and gave issues when trying to have both a shadow and radius.

**Table Cell 2:**

```
 - UITableViewCell
     - UIView (content view)
         - UIView (Shadow view)
             - UIView (Card background)
                 - UIView x 3
                 - UIButton x 5
                 - UILabel x 3
                 - UITextView
                 - UIImageView x 2
```

This uses the same code to add the shadow and rounded corners.

To get the estimated height for the row I use the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let type = model.dataContent[indexPath.row]["type"].stringValue

    if type == MediaType.text.rawValue {
        return 150
    } else {
        return 500
    }
}
```

Inside `cellForRowAt` in my UITableViewController I have the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Create the custom cell
    let mediaTableCellIdentifier = "MediaCell"
    let textTableCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

    let type = MediaType(rawValue: model.dataContent[indexPath.row]["type"].stringValue)

    var cell: TableCell!
    if type == .text {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textTableCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TableTextCell
        if flowState == .individualPost {
            (cell as! TableTextCell).expandView()
        }
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: mediaTableCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TableMediaCell
        (cell as! TableMediaCell).postImageView.image = nil
    }

    cell.delegate = self

    if type == .image {
        let cell = cell as! TableMediaCell
        let urlString = model.dataContent[indexPath.row]["img"]["loc"].stringValue

        // Check if we have an image stored in our cache for the image URL. If not, download it.
        if let cellImage = model.imageCache[urlString] {
            cell.postImageView.image = cellImage
        }
        else {
            model.downloadImage(
                atIndexPath: indexPath,
                type: type!,
                progress: { percentage in
                    cell.progressView.isHidden = false
                    cell.progressView.updateCirclePath(percentage: percentage)
                },
                completion: { [weak self] error, image in
                    if let strongSelf = self {
                        if error == nil {
                            // Store the image in to our cache
                            strongSelf.model.imageCache[urlString] = image
                            // Update the cell with our image
                            if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableMediaCell {
                                cellToUpdate.postImageView.image = image
                                cellToUpdate.progressView.resetCircleAnimation()
                                cellToUpdate.progressView.isHidden = true
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            print("Error downloading image: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    } else if type == .video {
        let cell = cell as! TableMediaCell
        let urlString = "\(CloudFrontURL.video.rawValue)/\(model.dataContent[indexPath.row]["video"]["loc"].stringValue)"
        if let cellVideo = model.videoCache[urlString] {
            cell.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: cellVideo))
            cell.videoPlayer!.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none
            cell.videoView.playerLayer.player = cell.videoPlayer
        } else {
            let videoURL = URL(string: urlString)

            cell.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
            model.videoCache[urlString] = cell.videoPlayer?.currentItem?.asset
            cell.videoPlayer!.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none

            cell.videoView.playerLayer.player = cell.videoPlayer
        }
    }

    cell.caption.text = model.dataContent[indexPath.row]["caption"].stringValue
    cell.caption.isHidden = true
    model.retrieveCaption(at: indexPath, forCell: cell, withFont: cell.caption.font!) { (caption, cellToUpdate) in
        if let theCell = cellToUpdate {
            theCell.caption.attributedText = caption
            theCell.caption.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    cell.commentCount.text = model.dataContent[indexPath.row]["commentsCount"].stringValue

    // Enable/Disable the controls based on our settings
    cell.controlsEnabled = controlsEnabled
    // Provide each cell with our data
    cell.model = model
    // Setting this makes the controls update its data automatically.
    cell.indexPath = indexPath

    // If we've reached the last post in our loaded data, get the next page of posts (unless it's an individual post).
    if (indexPath.row == model.dataContent.count - 3 && !lastItemReached && flowState != .individualPost) {
        stateMachine.enterState(.retrievingNextPage)
    }

    return cell
}
```

When I set the indexPath of both UITableViewCells this code is called inside the custom cell class to update the cell:

```
var indexPath: IndexPath {
    get {
        // Return the internalIndexPath when we ask for the indexPath.
        return internalIndexPath
    }
    set {
        // Set the internalIndexPath to the value supplied to indexPath.
        internalIndexPath = newValue

        // Calculate the number of points on a post.
        let points = model.dataContent[self.indexPath.row]["upVotes"].intValue - model.dataContent[self.indexPath.row]["downVotes"].intValue
        pointsLabel.text = "\(points)"
        // Show the upload time of the post.
        let uploadTimeString = model.dataContent[self.indexPath.row]["timestamp"].stringValue

        let date = DateFormatter.formatter.date(from: uploadTimeString)
        let dateString = date?.relativeTime
        uploadTime.text = dateString

        if let type = MediaType(rawValue: model.dataContent[self.indexPath.row]["type"].stringValue) {
            self.type = type
        }

        /// Adjust up/down arrows
        if (model.dataContent[self.indexPath.row]["userVote"]["likeState"] != nil) {
            switch model.dataContent[self.indexPath.row]["userVote"]["likeState"].stringValue {
            case LikeState.Likes.rawValue:
                thumbsUpButton.isSelected = true
                thumbsDownButton.isSelected = false
            case LikeState.Dislikes.rawValue:
                thumbsUpButton.isSelected = false
                thumbsDownButton.isSelected = true
            case LikeState.Neither.rawValue:
                thumbsUpButton.isSelected = false
                thumbsDownButton.isSelected = false
            default:
                break
            }
        } else {
            thumbsUpButton.isSelected = false
            thumbsDownButton.isSelected = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think you can share the code So, I can take a look at it?

Comment: I think something is wrong with your code, because I have never experienced the scroll to be slow, even during using e.g. 25 prototype cells with dynamically loading images and fetching prices online... if you can share your implementation we may highlight the... khm glitches in your snippet which could / would case issues in your app, meanwhile you can read about possible issues __[here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.onlc0wbbi)__ (external site).

Comment: @holex Theres quite a lot of code! That's one of the guides that I've looked at, but wasn't helpful in solving the problem. I will update this question with code later :)

Comment: @Prav updated the question with code

Comment: @holex updated the question with code

Comment: Can you test this: filter out all video items from your data, so that you only dequeue image cells, and then test the scrolling. It is likely that the AV player does something on the main thread, and therefore slows down the scrolling performance.

Comment: @almas yeah I've tried that too actually, it doesn't make any difference to scrolling performance!

Comment: Ok, then can you implement "heightForRowAtIndexPath" and return a static height there (don't use estimated height and automatic dimension for this test)? May be autolayout calculations slow down the performance.

Comment: @almas Yep it does make it much smoother with a fixed height. Not completely smooth but a noticeable improvement.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. So if it's autolayout, then I don't even know what you can do to improve it. You can either simplify your UI, or you can calculate heights manually in the code. That's exactly what I had to do recently with one of my projects. Autolayout is great, but sometimes very expensive in CPU resources.

Answer (score 0):

One very obvious reason for your `UITableView` to display slow is that your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is way too long. You need to refactor your code. Keep the Cell declaration itself short and simple.

It's best practise to declaration the Cell at the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and call a `bindData` function that fills the Cell with content. For example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! Cell

        let content = contentArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.bindData(content)

        return cell
    }
}

extension Cell {
    bindData(content: ContentStruct) {
         label.text = content.name
    }   
}
```

Also in your case, you should refactor between a function that sets the content and a function that sets the properties. To keep each function even shorter.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! Cell

        let content = contentArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.bindData(content)
        cell.setProperties

        return cell
    }
}

extension Cell {
    bindData(content: ContentStruct) {
         label.text = content.name
    }

    setProperties() {

        // set stuff like:
        // Enable/Disable the controls based on our settings
        cell.controlsEnabled = controlsEnabled
        // Provide each cell with our data
        cell.model = model
        // Setting this makes the controls update its data automatically.
        cell.indexPath = indexPath

        // If we've reached the last post in our loaded data, get the next page of posts (unless it's an individual post).
        if (indexPath.row == model.dataContent.count - 3 && !lastItemReached && flowState != .individualPost) {
            stateMachine.enterState(.retrievingNextPage)
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: This code looks better, but it won't improve the performance. "bindData" method will be called synchronously anyway.

Comment: it did for me. i have had a cellForRowAtIndexPath with 150+ lines. refactored it and it improved the performance noticeable

Comment: Why would it increase the performance if it's doing the exact same thing just in another function?

Comment: i have refactored my code after intense research and i came up with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124509/uitableview-lags-when-scrolling and it helped me